# JavaScript calculator, double-check the algebra

Tags: javascript, math, algebra

I wrote this JavaScript calculator for finding the area and circumference of a circle. I'm 99% sure the JavaScript is fine apart from the algebraic bit. I was hoping for someone to check it.

Here it is including the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/B89eC/

```
function Radius(Atext, form) {
    var A = parseFloat(Atext);
    form.Answer.value = Math.PI * (Math.pow(A, 2));
}

function Diameter(Btext, form) {
    var B = parseFloat(Btext);
    form.Answer.value = (Math.PI / 4) * (Math.pow(B, 2));
}

function Circumference(Ctext, form) {
    var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
    form.Answer.value = Math.PI * (Math.pow(((C / Math.PI) / 2), 2));
}

function RadiusC(Dtext, form) {
    var D = parseFloat(Dtext);
    form.Answer2.value = Math.PI * (2 * D);
}

function DiameterC(Etext, form) {
    var E = parseFloat(Etext);
    form.Answer2.value = Math.PI * E;
}

function AreaC(Ftext, form) {
    var F = parseFloat(Ftext);
    form.Answer2.value = Math.PI * (2 * (Math.sqrt(F / Math.PI)));
}
```

Comment: I checked it, seems to work.

Comment: Even the right formulas?

Comment: Can help you if you give the function specifications (input, output). We shouldn't play guesswork.